# how to remove timestamp from a variable of type Date?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a variable of type Date,whose value is passed from a form,but it stores the timestamp as 00:00,how do i remove that timestamp,or how do i get to set proper time??

This is model class :

```
     public class Offer {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
     @GenericGenerator(
      name = "UUID",
       strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
        )
     @Column(name = "offercode", updatable = false, nullable = false)

      private String offercode;

      @NotBlank
      private String offerName;

      private Date effectiveDate;
      }
```

JSP code:

```
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/offer"  method="post">
    <tr><th>
    Offer Name<input type="text" name="offerName" placeholder="enter offer 
    name" required/><br></th></tr>
    <tr><th>
     Effective-Date<input type="text" name="effectiveDate" 
    placeholder="1/1/1990" required/><br></th></tr>
    <tr><th>
    Expiration Date<input type="text" name="expiryDate" 
     placeholder="1/1/1990" required/><br></th></tr>
    <tr><th>
     <input type="submit" value="CREATE"><br></th></tr>
    </form></table>
    </center>
   </body>
```

Comment: The Date contains the number of millseconds since epoch.  To format it use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: The date contains a time, necessarily.  You can change it using java.util.Calendar.  Not sure what you mean by "proper time"?  `00:00` is 24 hour notation for midnight, aka `12:00 am`

Comment: use java.sql.date

Comment: @Taylor,it always shows time as 00:00,all the time!!

Comment: What do you want it to show?

Comment: @Taylor,i create an offer at 11:15AM,in DB it stores as 00:00,i want it to store as 11:15 itself..

Comment: This seems confusing, in your question you want to remove time information and in comment you ask to save time info also, Can you please elaborate what exactly you want ?

Comment: @Neha what is the database and datatype of `effectiveDate` ?

Comment: your problem stems from the fact that in java.util.Date, the time representation is stored as _transient_ (look at the source for Date.java) and so will not be persisted. You need to do what Shivangani Tandon suggests below with the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use SimpleDateFormat to format your date only for dd/MM/YYYY or you can put `@Temporal(TemporalType.Date)` on `private Date effectiveDate`